# Django Background Image Not Working How To Fix?

Tags: python, css, django

I am trying to make my background image for a website I am working on but when ever I try to make it, it appears white for that page [image](https://gyazo.com/29f6e7ee8192249b40a40d912f6941af) < as you can see the page just shows white I am not sure why it happens when ever I try to add a pg image

My Home Page The background line of code is the first 2 line of code

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        body {
          background-image: url("ok.png");
        }
        .sidenav2 h1 {
            margin-top: 190px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            margin-right: 150px;
            margin-left: 350px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #F7F9F9;
            display:block;
        

        }

        
        .sidenav3 h1 {
            margin-top: -125px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            margin-right: 150px;
            margin-left: 400px;
            padding-left: 290px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #F7F9F9;
            display:block;

        }

        .sidenav4 h1 {
            margin-top: -128px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            margin-right: 150px;
            margin-left: 800px;
            padding-left: 290px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #F7F9F9;
            display:block;

        }

        .sidenav5 h1 {
            margin-top: 328px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            margin-right: 150px;
            margin-left: 800px;
            padding-left: 290px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #F7F9F9;
            display:block;

        }

        .sidenav6 h1 {
            margin-top: -130px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            margin-right: 150px;
            margin-left: 400px;
            padding-left: 290px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #F7F9F9;
            display:block;

        }


        .sidenav7 h1 {
            margin-top: -130px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            margin-right: 150px;
            margin-left: 50px;
            padding-left: 290px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #F7F9F9;
            display:block;

        }


    </style>
</head>
```

[image] < The Image I am trying to add

Comment: where is the image located in your app? you're probably just not pointing to the right url

Comment: where is it suppose to be? on my template? because its on my desktop

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
body {
  background-image: url("ok.png");
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background-blend-mode: lighten;
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: does the image need to be in the web folder?

Comment: because it still not working not sure why

Comment: I mean I got it to work but the image is just now showing [IMAGE](https://gyazo.com/ff135fcc6f3d430c766fb43d03908a47) and [my code](https://gyazo.com/1aae79bebecea511226bdc30fc80ac10)

Comment: if your file is not in the same folder of your HTML or CSS file. you should specify the full path of the image in src.
if it's on the desktop. <img src="C:\Users\Brink\Desktop\ok.png">

and on Django, in settings.py and DEBUG should be True if your still in development